# How does Stride in unicode.RangeTable work?

Tags: unicode, go

I'd like some help on understanding the unicode package's [RangeTable](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#RangeTable).

Using this (supposedly helping) function:

```
func printChars(ranges []unicode.Range16) {
  for _, r := range ranges {

    if r.Hi >= 0x80 { // show only ascii
      break
    }
    fmt.Println("\nLo:", r.Lo, "Hi:", r.Hi, "Stride:", r.Stride)

    for c := r.Lo; c <= r.Hi; c++ {
      fmt.Print(string(c) + " ")
    }
  }
  fmt.Println()
}
```

For digits, I can do `printChars(unicode.Digit.R16)`, and the sequence of digits make sense to me.

```
 // Lo: 48 Hi: 57 Stride: 1
 // 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

However, to get punctuation `printChars(unicode.Punct.R16)` results in

```
 // Lo: 33 Hi: 35 Stride: 1
 // ! " #
 // Lo: 37 Hi: 42 Stride: 1
 // % & ' ( ) *
 // Lo: 44 Hi: 47 Stride: 1
 //  , - . /
 // Lo: 58 Hi: 59 Stride: 1
 // : ;
 // Lo: 63 Hi: 64 Stride: 1
 // ? @
 // Lo: 91 Hi: 93 Stride: 1
 // [ \ ]
 // Lo: 95 Hi: 123 Stride: 28
 // _ ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z {
```

I'm surprised that the lower case letters are included too. Also, what does "Stride" mean? It's 1 for all but the last, but the hi-lo difference varies.

As another example, `printChars(unicode.Pe.R16)`. I thought this should give only the end punctuation:

- ) right parenthesis    (U+0029, Pe)
- ] right square bracket (U+005D, Pe)
- } right curly bracket  (U+007D, Pe)

But instead my function prints

```
 // Lo: 41 Hi: 93 Stride: 52
 // ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ]
```

Presumably I'm completely misunderstanding the way this is supposed to work.

How might I correctly get a list of characters in a given category, for example, Punctuation End (Pe) as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stride is the step with which you have to iterate over the range. Let's heighten the boundary of `0x80` a bit and make the loop to iterate using `Stride`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
)

func printChars(ranges []unicode.Range16) {
  for _, r := range ranges {

    if r.Hi >= 0x100 {
      break
    }
    fmt.Println("\nLo:", r.Lo, "Hi:", r.Hi, "Stride:", r.Stride)

    for c := r.Lo; c <= r.Hi; c+=r.Stride {
      fmt.Print(string(c) + " ")
    }
  }
  fmt.Println()
}

func main() {
    printChars(unicode.Punct.R16)
}
```

And here is the output:

```
% go run main.go

Lo: 33 Hi: 35 Stride: 1
! " # 
Lo: 37 Hi: 42 Stride: 1
% & ' ( ) * 
Lo: 44 Hi: 47 Stride: 1
, - . / 
Lo: 58 Hi: 59 Stride: 1
: ; 
Lo: 63 Hi: 64 Stride: 1
? @ 
Lo: 91 Hi: 93 Stride: 1
[ \ ] 
Lo: 95 Hi: 123 Stride: 28
_ { 
Lo: 125 Hi: 161 Stride: 36
} ¡ 
Lo: 167 Hi: 171 Stride: 4
§ « 
Lo: 182 Hi: 183 Stride: 1
¶ · 
Lo: 187 Hi: 191 Stride: 4
» ¿
```

Looks pretty much correct to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a helper function which makes it easy to iterate over all runes contained in a RangeTable:

```
func RunesFromRange(tab *unicode.RangeTable) <-chan rune {
    res := make(chan rune)
    go func() {
        for _, r16 := range tab.R16 {
            for c := r16.Lo; c <= r16.Hi; c += r16.Stride {
                res <- rune(c)
            }
        }
        for _, r32 := range tab.R32 {
            for c := r32.Lo; c <= r32.Hi; c += r32.Stride {
                res <- rune(c)
            }
        }
        close(res)
    }()
    return res
}
```

The function can be used as follows:

```
for c := range RunesFromRange(unicode.Punct) {
    fmt.Printf("%04x %s\n", c, string(c))
}
```

Runnable code to play with is on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/1a4ZAHoMKt) (I like the characters starting with 0x 0df4 in the output).